# How to connect moto x to android studio

Tags: moto-x

I want to test my app to my device. I have moto x but i am not able to connect moto x to my android studio.can any one help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved,

I download the [Driver](https://motorola-mobility-en-in.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/89881/action/auth),then i went Device Manager and right click on the motorola device name and select uninstall

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable developer options in your device.
Steps are: settings->about-phone. Tap seven times on build number and you are a developer now. Now open developer options and enable usb-debug, good to go now.

Comment: already done that..

Comment: can you check adb integration in AS then. In your android studio check tools->android->adb-integration. Try unchecking and then checking it.